# Import a custom Linux image for POWER-IAAS part of the IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to import a cloud-enabled Debian Linux image for the Power architecture to run on the IBM public cloud, which supports this architecture.

I think I am following the instructions, but the behavior I am seeing is that, at image-import-time, after filling in all the relevant information, when I hit the "import" button, the GUI just exits silently, with no apparent effect, and no reported error.

I am reasonably experienced doing simple iaas stuff on AWS, but am new to the IBM cloud, and have not deployed a custom image on any cloud provider. I'm aware of "cloud-init", and have a reasonable general knowledge of what problem it solves (mapping cloud-provider metadata to config entries in the resulting VM at start-time), but not a great deal about how it actually works.

What I have done is:

- Got an IBM cloud account, and upgraded out of the free tier, for access to Power.
- Activated the Power Systems Virtual Server service.
- Activated the Cloud Object Storage service.
- Created a bucket in the COS.
- Created an HMAC-enabled service credential for this bucket.
- Uploaded my image, in .tar.gz format, to the bucket (via the CLI, it's too big to upload by GUI).

The image is from [here](https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/) -- that page is a bit vague on which cloud providers it may be expected to work with, but AFAIK the IBM cloud is the only public cloud supporting Power?

Then, from the Power Systems Virtual Server service page, I clicked the "Boot Images" item on the left, to show the empty list, then "Import Image" at the top of the list, and filled in the form. I have answers for all of the entries -- I can make up a new name, I know the region of my COS, the image file name" (the "key", in key-object storage parlance), the bucket name, and the access key and secret keys, which are available from the credential description in the COS panel.

Then the "import" button lights up, and I click it, and the import dialog disappears, no error is reported, and no image is imported.

There are various things that *might* be wrong that I'm not sure how to investigate.

It's possible the credential is not connected to the bucket in the right way, I didn't really understand the documentation about that, but in the GUI it looks like it's in the right scope and has the right data in it.

It's also possible that only certain types of images are allowed, and my image is failing some kind of validation check, but in that case I would expect an error message?

I have found the image-importing instructions for the non-Power-IAAS, but it seems like it's out of scope. I have also found some docs on how to prepare a custom image, but they also seem to be non-Power-IAAS.

What's the right way to do this?

Edit to add: Also tried doing this via the CLI ("ibmcloud pi image-import"), where it gets a time-out, apparently on the endpoint that's supposed to receive the image. Also, the command-line tool has an `--os-type` flag that apparently only takes `[aix | sles | redhat | ibmi]` -- my first attempt used `raw`, which is an error.

This is perhaps additional evidence that what I want to do is actually impossible?

Answer (score 0):

PowerVS supports only .ova images. Those are not the same supported by VMWare, for instance.

You can get from here https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/server/powervs/images/

Or you can use the images available in the regional pool of images:

```
ibmcloud pi image-list-catalog
```

Once you have your first VM up and running you can use https://github.com/ppc64le-cloud/pvsadm to create a new .ova. Today the tool only supports RHEL, CentOS and CoreOS.

If you want to easily play with PowerVS you can also use https://github.com/rpsene/powervs-actions.